# combining consecutive dates with rates

Tags: oracle11g, oracle12c

I am looking at option of how to merge consecutive dates in pl/sql. For eg i have data

```
StartDate | EndDate   | Rate

5/18/2017  5/18/2017  100
5/19/2017  5/19/2017  100
5/20/2017  5/20/2017  100
5/21/2017  5/21/2017  150
5/22/2017  5/22/2017  150
5/23/2017  5/23/2017  200
5/24/2017  5/24/2017  250
```

Output will be

```
StartDate | EndDate   | Rate

5/18/2017  5/20/2017  100
5/21/2017  5/22/2017  150
5/23/2017  5/23/2017  200
5/24/2017  5/24/2017  250
```

This is because 5/18 till 5/20 the rate is same.
21st and 22nd rate is same, where as 23rd and 24th the rates are different.

I do not have primary key for this table and also i tried using partition by, lag or lead functions but i could not get it. the data in this table has rows from 2015 to 2020. The above is sample from it.

Comment: So, in the INPUTS is the end_date always the same as start_date? (And if so, why do you even have two columns instead of one?) Then: are the dates all distinct, and all dates within the range are actually present in the table (no gaps)? Finally: can the rate ever be NULL, and if so how should that be handled? (Obviously it doesn't have to be handled if it can never happen in the first place.)

Comment: the table was created by someone else and it has both startdate and enddate.. I am not sure why they have it.  yes, There are no gaps all dates are present. for some of them both startdate and enddate are same. Rate never has NULL.. actually it is hotel room rate.. so we have startdate , enddate, rateofroom on that date.

Comment: You said "for **some** of them both startdate and enddate are same." For **some** of them or for **all** of them? That makes a huge difference. In your sample data, they are the same for ALL rows. If in some rows they may be different, it would be best to edit your post to illustrate that in the sample inputs.

Comment: for some of them only..

Comment: ...still waiting for you to edit your post to illustrate rows where the startdate and enddate are NOT equal, and what the output should look like for those rows.